# ReactJS Display API in Component

Tags: json, api, reactjs

I am new to react. I am using an api in the form of

```
{
 "category": "dogs",
 "available": [
   {
     "name": "pedro",
     "breed": "chihuahua"
   },
   {
     "name": "roxane"
     "breed": "beagle"
    }
 ]
},
{
"category": "cat",
"available": [
  {
    "name": "garfield",
    "breed": "tobby"
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to display ALL the pets available from the same category in name-breed pairs.

**Example:** Display all dogs

Pedro

Chihuahua

Roxane

Beagle

but that array is giving me hard times.

**Attempt**

*App.jsx*

```
        {this.state.data.map((availablePets, i) => <Content key = {i} data = {Content} />)}
```

*Content.jsx*

```
{this.props.data.available[WhatDoIPutHere?].name}
{this.props.data.available[ajsnxnnx].breed}
```

**Is there another way to display ALL the available pets from the same category in name-breed pairs?**

**SOLVED**

```
 {this.props.data.faqs.map((QA,i) => 
            <div key={i}>
            <h4>{this.props.data.category[i].name}</h4>
            <p>{this.props.data.category[i].breed}</p>
            </div>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not dynamic.

This will be a better solution.

```
{
  this.props.data.faqs.map((QA,i) => {
    const pets = QA.available.map((pets, j) => {
       return <div key={j}  
          <h4>{pets.breed}</h4>
          <p>{pets.name}</p>
        </div>
    })
     return <div key={i}>
       <h4>{QA.category}</h4>
       {pets}
    </div>
  })
}
```